# Html tag was broken when i use a Apache common email

Tags: java, html, apache-commons

I sent Email by Apache Commons Email lib.

but "url in img" and "id in div" were removed in my email received.

Why remove Html tag information ?

How can i maintain html tag ?

**Java code :**

```
    HtmlEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
    htmlEmail.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());

    htmlEmail.setHostName(smtpSetting.getHostname());
    htmlEmail.setSmtpPort(smtpSetting.getPort());

    htmlEmail.setSSLCheckServerIdentity(true);
    htmlEmail.setSSLOnConnect(true);

    String smtpUser = smtpSetting.getUserId();
    String smtpPassword = encryption.decryptString(smtpSetting.getPassword());

    htmlEmail.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(smtpUser, smtpPassword));

    htmlEmail.setFrom(smtpSetting.getUserId(), smtpSetting.getUserId());
    htmlEmail.addTo(to);
    htmlEmail.setSubject(subject);
    htmlEmail.setHtmlMsg(content);
    htmlEmail.send();
```

**Html:**

```
        <div style="min-width:614px; min-height:381px">
            <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; width : 614px; height: 381px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; background:#ffffff; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #bababa; -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #bababa; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #bababa; overflow:hidden;">
                <div style="background:#2c3a3d; width:614px; height:62px;">
                    <img
                        url="localhost:9000/assets/images/logo_type1.png" style="display:inline-block; margin-top:15px; margin-left:23px; width:130px; height:32px; no-repeat center;"/>
                </div>
```

**Received Html:**

```
<div style="min-width:614px; min-height:381px">
                <div id="email-content-popup-box" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; width : 614px; height: 381px;>
 <img/>
                    </div>
```